# How is dynamic binding performed in java? (I have specific details)

Tags: java, dynamic-binding

I see some earlier questions similar to this, but I am looking for more specific answers.

1) In this case how/when does or what makes JVM to do perform dynamic binding?

- I try to call derived class method `derivedFunc1()` using super class reference variable `superobj`. It fails (My Assumption for fail: The compiler says the member `derivedFunc1()` does not fall under the memory that is allocated(or restricted) for super class reference variable.)
- I try to call method `superFunc1()` using super class reference variable `superobj`. Here inspite of having `superFunc1()` in super class it "somehow" calls `superFunc1()` from derived class. (This is contradicting my assumption, as accessing beyond its restricted scope of memory).

So my questions:

1) How `superobj` is able access derived class member `superFunc1()` but not able to access the other derived class member `derivedFunc1()`.

2) Who/what makes a call for JVM to do perform dynamic binding?

[image] 
Edit: The image might not be valid as I came to know "derived class object does not create super class object"

```
import java.util.*;  
import java.text.*;

public class MyLocale {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySuper superobj=new MyDerived();
        superobj.derivedFunc1(); //Statment1: fails because it cannot call functions from  derived class. (Okay I understand this part) 
        superobj.superFunc1(); //Statment2: has 2 options (one in super, one in derived) to call from and here it calls derived function. 

    }

}

class MySuper {
    void superFunc1() {
        System.out.println("Super");
    }

}
class MyDerived extends MySuper{
    void derivedFunc1() {
        System.out.println("Derived");
    }
    void superFunc1() {
        System.out.println("Derived");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read this thing https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html and fix your terminology so it's clear what you're asking. Try to stick to 'method', don't say things like 'it fails' without being explicit about what happens and clarify the relationship you want your classes to have. 'Superclass' and 'Base class' are synonyms, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things happening.

1) `MyBase` is a subclass of `MySuper` which means that `superFunc1()` of `MyBase` is overriding `superFunc1()` of `MySuper`.

2) `MySuper superobj=new MyBase();` is taking a `MyBase` instance but telling the compiler to treat it as a `MySuper`.

3) `MySuper` only has one method (`superFunc1`), so that's the only method that you can invoke on `superobj`

4) however, at runtime, the JVM does a dynamic lookup (`invokevirtual`) of `superFunc1` on `superobj` which is actually an instance of `MyBase`, so it invokes `MyBase.superFunc1`.

Relevant reading: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076949/learn-java/how-the-java-virtual-machine-handles-method-invocation-and-return.html

Comment: okay but whats  restricting `superobj` to access `baseFunc1()` but okay to access `superFunc1`.

Comment: @sql_dummy the compiler: the compiler treats `superobj` as an instance of `MySuper` (because that's what `superobj` is declared as). `MySuper` doesn't have `baseFunc1`, so the compiler gives you an error.

Comment: So in the case of `superFunc1()` why dint the compiler just resolve to func in super class but instead switch to dynamic binding. (Am sorry I am having trouble understanding the article you provided, I will try to go through it few more times, but meanwhile I accept the help with comments).

Comment: The compiler doesn't actually do function invocation. At compile-time it just checks whether the code is valid and then at runtime the jvm uses an `invokedynamic` call to resolve `superFunc1`. `invokedynamic` will look at the instance its invoked on (`MyBase`). For `baseFunc1` it doesn't even get to that point (if it did, it would work), because the compiler emits an error first.